# this.src removing backslashes in path to file

Tags: html

I'm unsure why this is happening but whenever I do the following

```
    <img src=\"Images\\{reader[2]}\" onmouseover=\"this.src='Images\\White\\{reader[2]}';\">
```

It outputs the following in the source code

```
    <img onmouseover="this.src='Images\White\settings.png';" src="ImagesWhitesettings.png">
```

Why is it removing the backslashes?

Comment: "It outputs the following in the source code"? Javascript doesn't change the source code. Are you looking at the DOM? How?

Comment: What is now called inspect element in IE used to be called view source, which is why I phrased it that way.

Comment: That's not true. The two are very different - one shows the source code as it came in HTML from the server, the second formats the DOM in a human-readable (and usable) way - basically translating the DOM back to HTML with a few extra features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\` indicates the start of [an escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Escaping_characters) in a JavaScript string literal.

To include `\` as data you have to use the escape sequence for it: `\\`.

That said, URLs use `/` and not `\` as path separators.

Comment: In my code I have \\ I cleaned it up for above purposes. Thank you though switching to forward slash resolved. Kind of weird the double acted that way.

Comment: @Jordan Why would you do that? Show us the **actual** code and stop wasting everyone's time. I, frankly, don't believe you, because https://jsfiddle.net/6r9ugzbs/1/

Comment: @Jordan Don't do that. Put your actual code there - this is not "cleaning up", it's making the sample utterly worthless.

Comment: @Jordan — You won't get the result you describe if the JS embedded in HTML sent to the browser has ``\\`` in it. Other factors would have to be involved.

Comment: The double worked for my img src, so logicially it should have worked with the onmouseover. I appreciate your help with that. And I would hardly call it a waste of time seeing as though I learned something valuable this morning. Thanks again.

Comment: "The double worked for my img src, so logicially it should have worked with the onmouseover." No, because `src` is just HTML, `onmouseover` contains JavaScript code.

Comment: @Jordan Okay, now it's obvious that you need to double encode. Your code (whatever it is, C#?) encodes the backslash, but then you need to encode that again to be valid Javascript. You actually need *quadruple* backslashes :)

Comment: @Luaan yeah that's a headache, haha, Ill take the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Try using forward slashes "/", because backslashes are used to escape characters.

Comment: While this is true, OP really needs to know more on what's happening here, as they sometimes may need a backslash in a string.